# Canvas background not behind objects

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

So I'm using fabric.js and a few separate .php pages to display different sized canvases. On one page I have:

```
<canvas width="792" height="1008" id="c" style="background: url('./images/backgrounds/AmericanFlagBackground11x14.jpg')"></canvas>
```

And on another page I have:

```
<canvas width="792" height="1008" id="c" style="background: url('./images/backgrounds/AmericanFlagBackground16x20.jpg')"></canvas>
```

and get the background I want but when I go to add an object they spawn behind the background. How can I force the image to be behind added objects like text and images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the canvas­*'s* background image using inline style attribute, set it in your css file , like so ...

```
#c {
   background: url(./images/backgrounds/AmericanFlagBackground11x14.jpg)
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
   top: 100,
   left: 100,
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   fill: '#07C',
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

```css
#c {
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Q6aZlme.jpg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is close however how would I handle the other dimensions? I've tried giving a larger canvas the id of d `#d {
  background: url(./images/backgrounds/AmericanFlagBackground16x20.jpg)
}` without luck. Do I need to create new canvas vars?

Comment: um.. what you mean by '*handle the other dimensions*' ?

Comment: Apologies. I'm going to reform my question

Comment: I attempted to restate my question. Sorry, I may be overcomplicating things- if need be I can try and rewrite it but basically I'm trying to set multiple IDs based on your answer AND still take advantage of all the JS I have set for the original canvas but the new canvases aren't picking up the JS as the original does.

Comment: um.. if I got you correctly then, it has nothing to do with your current question *(and with this solution)*. if you have multiple canvases in your DOM then obviously you need to create a new instance of `fabric.Canvas('canvasID')` for each canvas to make the JS work for them. or if you have multiple canvases on top of each other then you need to add the object to the top most canvas to make it visible.

Comment: you should rather create a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue, so that I can get a better understanding.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22q8mb8p/4/). I've got two canvases and want to be able to display different backgrounds (as you suggested) however I'd like to be able to use the same controls on a per-canvas basis. In the fiddle I'm forced to use one page for both canvases but I've I'd be using separate pages (so there'd only be one canvas and set of controls per page). Same styling on image upload on each canvas, just different sized canvases.

Comment: sorry to say, but your original question was *how to set background image behind the object*, which I answer correctly and it did solve your problem as it seems. but now you are asking a completely different question which has nothing to do with your current question. you should post a new question if you need further help.
**heads up:** since you're gonna use one canvas on each page, you can use same `id` for all of the canvases.

Comment: My bad. Thank you for your help. I'll submit a new question if I don't figure this out. Marked as solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine?

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=1&w=100&h=100')";
setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(10, 10, 1000, 1000);
}, 1000 * 2);
```